# is there a better way of retrieving my settings?

Tags: vb.net

I'm not an IT professional so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

When writing a program I add a class `SettingsIni` that reads a text file of keys and values. I find this method really flexible as settings can be added or changed without altering any code, regardless of what application I have attached it to.
Here's the main code.

```
Public Shared Sub Load()

    Using settingsReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "settings.ini")
        Do While settingsReader.Peek > -1
            Dim line As String = settingsReader.ReadLine
            Dim keysAndValues() As String = line.Split("="c)  
            settingsTable.Add(keysAndValues(0).Trim, keysAndValues(1).Trim)

            Loop
    End Using
End Sub


Public Shared Function GetValue(ByVal key As String)
    Dim value As String = settingsTable(key)
    Return value
End Function
```

This allows you to use a setting within your code by calling the `SettingsIni.GetValue` method.

For example:

```
watcher = New FileSystemWatcher(SettingsIni.GetValue("inputDir"), "*" & SettingsIni.GetValue("extn")).
```

I find this makes my code esay to read.
My problem is the values in this case, `inputDir` and `extn`, are typed freehand and not checked by intellisense. I'm always worried that I may make a typo in an infrequently used branch of an application and miss it during testing.
Is there a best practice method for retrieving settings? or a way around these unchecked freehand typed values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A best practice for your code example would be to use Constants for the possible settings.

```
Class Settings
    Const inputDir as String = "inputDir"
    Const extn as String = "extn"
End Class


watcher = New FileSystemWatcher(SettingsIni.GetValue(Settings.inputDir), "*" & SettingsIni.GetValue(Settings.extn))
```

Comment: I like this answer. It keeps the basic format and gives me the error correcting of intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a number you could do these 3 things:

1. Check if is numeric - using IsNumeric function
2. Check if it is whole number - using Int function, like: if Int(number)=number
3. Check for the valid range, like: if number>=lowerbound and number<=upperbound

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using VB.NET?
If so, there is the handy "Settings"-menu under "my project". It offers a way to store the settings for your program and retrieve them via "my.settings.YOURKEY". The advantage is, that type securtiy is enforced on this level.
Additionally, you can also store "resources" almost the same way - but resources are better suited for strings / pictures etc. But they are expecially good if you want to translate your program.

As for your current problem:
Store the path in the settings, this way you do not need to change alll your code immidiately but you can use your system and never misspell anything.

Comment: Dammit, I have accidentally not logged in :(

Comment: I'll go have a look at that and see if it's what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on you. You are the one to check almost  all the things inside quotes, not the intellisense.

But you still use `Try-Catch` block:

```
Try
  Dim value As String = settingsTable(key)
  Return value
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.ToString)
  Return ""
End Try
```

So you will get an message box if you are trying to access a non-existing setting that you may have mistyped.

Comment: I edited the Try Catch blocks out of the above code to make it readable for the question, but they are there in the full code. Problem is if I catch a mistake to correct it I need to edit the code and redeploy the application which can be a real nuisance if it's a service that's gone live.